# How to make $('#slidepanel').slidepanel("hide") work with Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a modal dialog panel with html input controls, which I want to open like a popup sliding on click of a button.
**jQuery slidePanel v0.2.2**

The code for opening dialog works which is

```
$('#slidepanel').slidepanel("show")
```

The issue is in closing the dialog by the following code

```
$('#slidepanel').slidepanel("hide")
```

The same hide code was working with jquery but is problematic through Angular.js. Any help appreciated!

Comment: _but is problematic through Angular.js_ - Care to show us what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery to manipulate the "show" and "hide" after the DOM has loaded, jQuery doesn't know those elements exist.

my suggestion is to use  jQuery's on() in order to delegate events and select dynamically generated classes:

```
$(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.show',function(){
  ....
});

$(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.hide',function(){
  ....
});
```